# How to query Spring boot server from Angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I made a server using Spring boot, which listens to

`@GetMapping("/portGroup/{portGroup}/date/{date}")`

When I try querying this endpoint, I get back a 400 "Bad Request" error.

What is the proper way to send a `GET` request to this endpoint from my Angular client?

Comment: maybe posting some code in the beginning ;-) .. maybe you have a wrong encoded url? especially cause of the date field

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to be easier to read, but you should edit your question to include the code you've tried. By including the code you've tried, you'll be more likely to receive help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your api endpoint will be like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/portGroup/{portGroup}/date/{date}")
public String getBook(@PathVariable int portGroup, @PathVariable String date) {
    // code here
    System.out.println("portGroup: "+ portGroup);
    System.out.println("date: "+date);
    return null;
}
```

So, you have to make the get call like from you angular application (instead of localhost:8080 git your domain and port):

```
localhost:8080/portGroup/1/date/1
```